# Changing the value of a UITextField inside a tableViewCell with a button using a delegate

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a tableView inside a UIView, this tableview has three buttons, one is already working which is the green X I also have two buttons to increase and decrease the value in the textfield to the right, these ones are the ones I need help with.

[image]

The @IBActions for the buttons in the cell call the delegate functions in the cell's Superview, the button with the green X is already working, doing what it's supposed to do, but what I need to do now is how to program the behavior of the buttons that increase / decrease the Quantity (Cantidad) of the products, my delegate function is already handling the data, but now I need them to handle the Cantidad TextField value as well, so that when the user presses the buttons the cantidadTextField.text is updated.

I just need to know how can I access the cantidadTextField.text property inside the cell from the class that is hosting the TableVIew.

I can do this in the CellForRowAtIndexPath method when the cell is created but I need to do it inside the delegate's methods.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to update the textField from the tableviewcontroller? From what I understood, the image that you posted in the question would be a uitableviewcell, isn't it? (Except for the "Productos" title)

The best aproach would to manage all this behaviour inside the uitableviewcell. What I mean with this is to update the uitextfield in each @IBAction inside the controller. Something like the following:

```
@IBAction func plusPressed() { 
   let previousAmount = Int(cantidadTextField.text!)
   cantidadTextField.text = "\(previousAmount + 1)"
}

@IBAction func minusPressed() { 
   let previousAmount = Int(cantidadTextField.text!)

   guard let previousAmount > 1 else { return }

   cantidadTextField.text = "\(previousAmount - 1)"
}
```

If this aproach cannot be done and you must update it from the controller, you could save a reference to the cell when you are creating it in a variable in the controller. But beware that due to cell reuse, this cell may be reused for another "producto" afterwards while scrolling, for example.

Maybe with some code we can see the problem better!

Comment: The reason I don't want to update the textField directly from the cell is because I need a variable that is stored into a plist that is loaded into the superview, so if I would need to pass the value from the superview to the cell I would add an additional complexity. 

The reason I'm not creating a variable in the controller is precisely due to cell reuse.

I can share my code but the View it's pretty complex because the UIView has three custom TableViews and each one of them has different behaviors and different Nibs depending on the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

What I need to do was to access the textfield directly from the cell, update the textfield's value and then call the delegate which then updates the data as well.

This is one of the methods.

```
@IBAction func increaseAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let cantidadStr = cantidadProducto.text

    if let cantidadInt = Int(cantidadStr!) {
        var cantidad = cantidadInt
        cantidad += 1
        let strCantidad = String(cantidad)

        cantidadProducto.text = strCantidad
    }

    self.delegate?.increaseProductQuantityTapped(sender: self, at: indexPath)

}
```

And the other one

```
@IBAction func decreaseAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let cantidadStr = cantidadProducto.text

    if let cantidadInt = Int(cantidadStr!) {
        var cantidad = cantidadInt
        if cantidad > 1 {
            cantidad -= 1
            let strCantidad = String(cantidad)

            cantidadProducto.text = strCantidad

            self.delegate?.decreaseProductQuantityTapped(sender: self, at: indexPath)
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```